# How to set vibration for local notification using ionic & cordova?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Could anyone tell how to set vibration in local notification for every notification i want to get vibrate in my mobile.

**Local Notification Sample Code:**

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
  id    : remId,
  title : name.innerHTML,
  text  : note.value,                
  at    : alertDate              
});
```

**Vibrate Code:**

```
$cordovaVibration.vibrate(200);
```

Please help me.. if is it possible, please give me a good solution for me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the vibration plugin: [cordova-plugin-vibration](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration)

Adding vibration is as simple as:

```
navigator.vibrate(1500);
```

Coupled with a notification, you can do something like this:

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.add({

        id: "12345",
        message: "Test",
        title: "Test",
        autoCancel: false,
        sound: null,
        date: new Date(),

    }).then(function () {

        navigator.vibrate(1500);
});
```